# SQL Update from one table to another table, no common data

Tags: mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper

In my **Customer** table, there is a row called *inactive_status*, which is always set to 'Active'. This is unless *is_paid* (located in the **Billing_Info** table) is set to 0. I need to use the Update command, but cannot figure it out. Here is what I have so far:

```
UPDATE Customer
SET inactive_status = 'INACTIVE'
WHERE
(SELECT is_paid
FROM Billing_Info
WHERE billing_info.is_paid = 0);
```

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE billing_info ( 
    billing_info_id INT, 
    bill_day_id INT, 
    is_past_due NUMBER(1,0) NOT NULL, 
    date_last_paid DATE, 
    is_paid_this_month NUMBER(1,0) NOT NULL, 
    paid_amount DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL, 
    bill_amount DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT billing_info_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(billing_info_id) );

CREATE TABLE customer ( 
    customer_id INT, 
    join_date DATE NOT NULL, 
    billing_info_id INT NOT NULL, 
    inactive_status VARCHAR2(25), 
    contact_info_id INT NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT customer_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (customer_id) );
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: There should be a customer_id in your billing_info table. Otherwise how do you know which Cusomters should be updated?

Comment: There is, but the customer_id doesn't have anything to do with the inactive_status. I'm using someone else's work and cannot go back and change anything. Basically each customer has information stored in multiple tables, and the data that I am dealing with now has no links between them, but needs to be linked.

Comment: Please post your DDL (create table statements) for both tables `Customer` and `Billing_Info`.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE billing_info`
`(`
 `billing_info_id INT,`
 `bill_day_id INT,`
 `is_past_due NUMBER(1,0) NOT NULL,`
 `date_last_paid DATE,`
 `is_paid_this_month NUMBER(1,0) NOT NULL,`
 `paid_amount DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL,`
 `bill_amount DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL,`
 `CONSTRAINT billing_info_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(billing_info_id)`
`);`

Comment: `CREATE TABLE customer`
`(`
 `customer_id INT,`
 `join_date DATE NOT NULL,`
 `billing_info_id INT NOT NULL,`
 `inactive_status VARCHAR2(25),`
 `contact_info_id INT NOT NULL,`
 `CONSTRAINT customer_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)`
`);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should investigate the use of triggers. Setting a trigger such that a particular customer's `inactive_status` updates to `'INACTIVE'` when their `is_paid` flag changes to 0 would be the perfect solution.

Comment: Very good suggestion! It would have been better for me if I was familiar with triggers, but unfortunately I'm just a beginner. Thank you!

I found that I could either do this, or put inactive_status in the table Billing_Info and Update that way. Didn't think it would work, but hey, I can't complain.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that connects a `customer` to a `billing_info` is `billing_info_id`.

If your RDBMS is Oracle your `UPDATE` query might look like this

```
UPDATE (SELECT c.inactive_status 
          FROM customer c INNER JOIN
               billing_info b ON c.billing_info_id = b.billing_info_id
         WHERE b.is_paid_this_month = 0)
   SET inactive_status = 'INACTIVE';
```

That is assuming that the relation is 1 to 1, and that is hard to tell for sure from your ddl.

Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/de0d3/5)